# Probability problem about repeated permutations

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-variables

I have a box with $n$ red balls and $n$ blue balls, and I pick them one by one. When the color of the ball that I picked is different from the color of the previous ball, I earn a point. Let $X$ be the random variable that represent the number of the point that I make. Calculate its distribution and expected value.

I think that the best way to approach this problem is to represent the possible games with the possible permutations of a string of $n$ times the letter R and $n$ times the letter B, so if I indicate my $\Omega$ as the set of permutations of $n$ R's and $n$ B's, I have that:
$$|\Omega|=\dfrac{(2n)!}{n!n!}$$
Now the problem is, what is the number of permutations in which there are exactly $k$ changes between R and B (in other words, the permutations of $k+1$ blocks of consecutive R or B)? If this number is $a_k$ then I can calculate
$$P(X=k)=\dfrac{a_k}{|\Omega|}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k$ be the number of switches between the colors. If $k$ is odd there will be $\frac{k+1}2$ groups of each color, and if $k$ is even there will be $\frac k2+1$ groups of the starting color and $\frac k2$ groups of the other color. Every group should contain at least one ball, and the other balls can be distributed between the groups of the corresponding color arbitrarily. Thus if $k$ is odd we need to distribute $n-\frac{k+1}2$ balls of each color between $\frac{k+1}2$ groups, so that by [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) the full number of combinations is:
$$
\binom{n-1}{\frac{k-1}2}\binom{n-1}{\frac{k-1}2}.
$$
Similarly for even $k$ one obtains:
$$
\binom{n-1}{\frac k2}\binom{n-1}{\frac k2-1}.
$$

Combining both expressions the probability to earn $k$ points can be written as:
$$
p_{k}(n)=2\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}
\binom{n-1}{\left\lfloor\frac{k-1}2\right\rfloor}\binom{n-1}{\left\lceil\frac{k-1}2\right\rceil},
$$
where the leading factor $2$ stays for the number of  ways to choose the starting color.